# How to reset axis without losing rotation?

Tags: modeling, axis

For some reason , when I press G and Z to move the selection up, the AXIS aren't all pointing upwards, it looks like they are pointing in the direction I rotated the objects in, which now makes everything super complicated. How can I fix this problem?
This is the GIF image that I can't embed to this post:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TTtB.jpg

Comment: If you look at the GIF, when I press G and Z to move the selection up, the AXIS aren't all pointing upwards, it looks like they are pointing in the direction I rotated the objects

Answer (score 1):

I think you accidentally changed your **transformation orientation** to **'Normal'** this will result in aligning the transformation axes to point in the direction of the mesh`s normals which is why you are experiencing weird transformations. This is a very common beginner mistake. The solution to this problem is simple just change the orientation to the default **'Global'**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked perfectly! One more question - do you know why when I scale the entire collection, the light moves further away not scaling proportionally with the rest of the scene?